# PHP Generate Math equation from answer

Tags: php, math, equation

I need some a function written in PHP to generate a simple math equation using the answer. For example:
Input:

```
6688650
```

Output: (Or something simmilar)

```
75 * 34 * (1 * (43 * 61))
```

Input:

```
249366
```

Output: (Or something simmilar)

```
(((99 + 87) + 95 * 99) * 26)
```

I came up with this prime factor generator but I need a way to turn the factors into a equation like the `(((99 + 87) + 95 * 99) * 26)`

```
function primefactor($num) {
    $sqrt = sqrt($num);
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $sqrt; $i++) {
        if ($num % $i == 0) {
            return array_merge(primefactor($num/$i), array($i));
        }
    }
    return array($num);
}
```

And with a number generator:

```
do {
    $num = mt_rand(6542,89523498);

} while (is_prime($num) & count(primefactor($num)) > 5);
```

This leaves me with somthing like:

```
Original: 78973465
Array ( [0] => 349 [1] => 271 [2] => 167 [3] => 5 )
```

Comment: Not a whole lot of PHP code here, so this is, unfortunately, off-topic. You need to show what you've tried. Whay you need is only one part of your question. The second part is some PHP code we can fix.

Comment: @tadman Well I cannot find any code to represent what I need. That is why I'm asking.

Comment: That's something you'll need to address first before asking the question. That's just how it works here. You give us broken code and we fix it, but we can't fix nothing. It doesn't matter how sad, misguided, or utterly wrong your code is, simply having it shows you're committed to solving the problem.

Comment: I'd start by writing a prime factorization function.  Then, from there, you can build whatever multiplication equation you want.

Comment: How is coming output or what is the formula that you get the answer from your input???

Comment: @tadman But if I had code then I wouldn't have to ask the problem. I need someone the steer me on the path of what this method would be called and maybe some sample code.

Comment: @tadman This site isn't just a Q&A to fix broken code, it's a Q&A for programming questions. It's not off-topic because OP didn't provide code, rather because the question itself is too broad.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Explaining the difference between those two things can be hard, so it's easier to keep it simple. If a question doesn't have associated code, or isn't related to code, it's probably off-topic. Very few questions with no code whatsoever are on-topic, and usually those are narrow enough in scope that they can be answered *with* code. There are other sites in the Stack Exchange network, like the [computer science site](https://cs.stackexchange.com) which can handle broader concerns.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I added some code to my question to help clairify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Concept

1. Convert your integer into an array of prime factors.
2. You can combine your prime factors however you choose to generate an equation.  However, this isn't a `1:1` function (unless the number is prime). So, you can be creative as to how you wish to combine the numbers back together.

*In this implementation*, I decided to generate random addition and combining of primes to form co-primes.

## Note

Creating an efficient way of prime factorization becomes a bit more complicated of a problem.  I wrote a very simple one here and, odds are, it will suit your needs.  However, if you need a method that is faster (or if you're dealing with much larger numbers or many more numbers) you may want to do some independent research.  I googled it and [this suggestion](https://www.thatsgeeky.com/2011/03/prime-factoring-with-php/) showed up.

## Code

```
<?php

$n = 6688650;

//generates a list of all factors
function primefactor($num) {
    $sqrt = sqrt($num);
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $sqrt; $i++) {
        if ($num % $i == 0) {
            return array_merge(primefactor($num/$i), array($i));
        }
    }
    return array($num);
}

//generates multiplication equation
//  Let's scramble those numbers

$factors = primefactor($n);

//let's randomly combine some of our prime factors
for ($i = 0, $len = count($factors); $i < $len; $i++) {
  if (mt_rand(0,1)) {
    $keys = array_rand($factors,2);
    $to = $factors[$keys[0]]*$factors[$keys[1]];
    array_push($factors, $to);
    unset($factors[$keys[0]]);
    unset($factors[$keys[1]]);
  }
}

//now, let's insert some random addition
foreach ($factors as $key => $value) {
  if (mt_rand(0,1)) {
    $delta = mt_rand(1,$factors[$key]-1);
    $factors[$key] = '(' . ($value-$delta) . '+' . $delta . ')';
  }
}

//output the information
$myValues = array_values($factors);
shuffle($myValues);
echo join('*',$myValues);

?>
```

## Some outputs

```
5185*(145+1145)
3*(59+27)*(23+62)*(269+36)
1462*(26+35)*5*5*(2+1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but none of the equations that this makes are equal to `6688650` the first one equals `1337730`

Comment: I think I'm missing something, this codes doesn't help because the equations dont equal the first number.

Comment: @Infrared Fixed it.  If this helps, if you could mark as solution/upvote, it'd be much appreciated.